# MySQL installation

Tags: mysql, linux, installation

I'm trying to install mysql-client so I use :

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server mysql-client
```

it loads some packages then it asks the classic :

```
Do you want to continue [Y/n]?
```

the problem is :  even if type Y the installation aborts

Comment: Can you paste the output you get after you say yes to the prompt?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried adding -y to the command?  This should override the prompt.  So it will look like:

`sudo apt-get install -y mysql-server mysql-client`

(Source: https://askubuntu.com/questions/509852/why-does-apt-get-abort-by-itself-as-though-id-pressed-n )

Answer (score 0):

-y option of apt-get install is just automatic yes to prompts and run non-interactively. It will also abort the installation for undesirable situation such as changing a held package or removing an essential package. The issue might be different, paste the output after you say Yes/Y.